# Normal Distribution Probability after finding value C

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

I am having trouble determining the probability of a $P(X > 8)$ for a problem that requires integrating a function to find the value of $c$.  I believe that I need to determine the mean and sigma in order to use the value of $(8-\mu)/\sigma$ to look up the probability using a $z$-score table.  My problem is not knowing how to determine the mean and sigma?  Here is the question:

The lifetime $X$ (in units of $10$ years) of a certain component of a home-heating furnace is a random variable with p.d.f.

$$f(x) =\left\{\begin{array}{cl} cx^2(1-x) & \text{if}\  0 < x < 1;\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{array}\right.$$

Determine the value of $c$ (which I've determined to be $12$ by integration).  Then find the probability that the life of such a component is more than eight years.

Comment: This PDF isn't normal, so you can't use the normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

As you did for obtaining $c=12$, you also need to integrate $f(x)$ for computing the probability. As Sean said, you can't use a $z$-score table because this is not a normal distribution. Also, you are asked to find the probability that the life is greater than $8$ years and the units of time are $10$ years, so you must find $P(X>0.8)$.
$$P(X>0.8)=\int_{0.8}^\infty f(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0.8}^112x^2(1-x)\mathrm{d}x+\int_1^\infty0\mathrm{d}x=\cdots=0.1808.$$